# How does Linux winbindd determine available domain controller?

Tags: linux, debian, kerberos, samba

We are actually in preparation of taking down one of our three domain controller (Win2k3). They are all serving the same domain.

Actually we still see connections incoming from Debian (5/6/7) Servers using winbindd for domain authentication to the server we want to take down.

/etc/krb5.conf on the debian hosts looks like this:

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = DOMAIN.COM
[realms]
        local.domain.com = {
                kdc = dc1.domain.com
                kdc = dc2.domain.com
                admin_server = dc1.domain.com
                default_domain = domain.com
        }
[domain_realm]
        .domain.com = DOMAIN.COM
        domain.com = DOMAIN.COM

[login]
        krb4_convert = true
        krb4_get_tickets = false
```

So how does winbindd determine the available domain-controller(dc)? 
Is it done by Broadcasts, even if there are dc entries in krb5.conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kerberos apps also look for DNS srv records to find the KDC's for a given realm.

See

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961719.aspx

My guess is that winbindd is using LDAP as well as kerberos.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
If found the "special" DNS-Entries in the DNS-Server.
They look like: _kerberos._tcp.domain.com

It seems to be very easy to resolv and ask them.